# I have Grails 3 project with Angular profile plug-In, Then how could I compress my Static Resources (JS and CSS files) files in GZip

Tags: caching, grails, gzip

I have Grails 3 project with Angular profile plug-In, 
Then how could I compress my Static Resources (JS and CSS files) *vendor.bundle.js* & *main.bundle.js* files in GZip

For this I have tried to install grails ui-performance & compress plugin but these where not supporting for grails 3.c version.
Now I want to compress my Static Resources (JS and CSS files) with minified version also in GZip format when client request for URL first time and after that files have to reside into client side and don't get download for every time when client request same URL i.e. caching.

Answer (score 0):

Asset pipeline can do this for you without additional plugins.  Your build.gradle can have a block like this to control asset management:

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    enableSourceMaps = false
    enableDigests = true
    skipNonDigests = true
    enableGzip = true
}
```

Modify what's enabled and not based on your needs.

Reference documentation is here: http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html